# Using macros for defining bus fields

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am trying to use macros to define different bus bitfields in the following way:

```
// bitfields NC  / YC          /  XC
//           0:2 / 3:(WIDTH+2) / (WIDTH+2+1): WIDTH+(WIDTH+2)
// first 
`ifdef VStrLite
    `define WIDTH = 10;
`else
    `define WIDTH = 11;
`endif

// then 
`define YC (`WIDTH +2) : 3
`define XC (`WIDTH + `WIDTH + 2) : (`WIDTH +2 + 1)

// finally in other module
line 1: assign endframe = (bus[`XC]==639 && bus[´YC]==479)? 1: 0;

line n: x <= bus[`XC] - CONST;
```

The result:

line 1: syntax error in left side of continuous assignment;

line n: Syntax in assignment statement l-value

When defining YC o XC in the usual form (`define YC 13:3) no errors appear.

Is it possible to call a macro within another macro? Any suggestion to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

1. You don't need `=` or the final `;` for defines. They should be:

```
`ifdef VStrLite
    `define WIDTH 10
`else
    `define WIDTH 11
`endif
```

2. `bus[´YC]==479` is incorrectly using a forward-tick (´) which is not allowed instead of a back-tick (`) - they are correct everywhere else.

Fix these and it should compile correctly.